# Why are scattering matrices unitary?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, scattering, s-matrix-theory, unitarity

In Griffith's QM book, he introduces scattering matrices as an end-of-the-chapter Problem 2.52.

For a Dirac-Delta potential $V(x) = \alpha \delta (x - x_0)$, I've derived the scattering matrix and observed that it is unitary $S^{-1} = S^{\dagger}$.

I'm trying to explain why this is intuitively, but I don't really have an intuitive picture of what hermitian conjugation $S^{\dagger}$ is doing here. Thoughts?

Comment: Scattering matrices are unitary in order to conserve probability.

Answer (score 8):

$S^{-1}=S^*$ is just the condition for unitarity. It is usually written as $S^*S=1$
(together with invertibility) and means that $\psi^*\psi$ doesn't change when $\psi$ is replaced by $S\psi$:

$(S\psi)^*(S\psi)=\psi^*S^*S\psi=\psi^*\psi$

Therefore probability is conserved, a must for a good scattering matrix.

In general, unitarity of the S-matrix is a consequence of the fact that the S-matrix is formally defined as a limit of products of unitary matrices, which are themselves unitary, though the analysis of the limit requires some care.

Actually, I noticed that I might have missed the point of your question, as you asked about what the adjoint does in your calculation. The delta of a selfadjoint operator is itself selfadjoint, did you mean that? Otherwise, please clarify your question!

Comment: In the book on Nuclera Physics by Weisskopf, there is a statement, that $\sum \limits_{\beta}S^{*}_{\alpha \beta}S_{\beta \gamma} = \delta_{\alpha \gamma}$. Is this the same to what you derived. I guess, that you are talking about $SS^{\dagger}=\mathbb{1}$, which in matrix form reads $\sum \limits_{\gamma}S^{*}_{\alpha \gamma}S_{\beta \gamma} = \delta_{\alpha \beta}$

Comment: @AlexanderCska: It is the same as $S^*S=1$, not $SS^*=1$.

Comment: So basically $S^{\dagger}S=\mathbb{1}$. Could you recommend a good book to learn more about the properties of the scattering matrix. In particular, the time reversal property (detailed balance). I am interested in how it works in nuclear physics. I tried to read Weisskopf, but didn't like it very much.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: Begin with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix - For a deep understanding, I recommend the book by R.G. Newton, Scattering Theory of Waves and Particles (2nd ed., Springer, New York 1982). This excludes QFT, where there is no book I can really recommend.

Comment: But Chapter 3 of Weinberg's vol.1 on QFT gives a sensible account, including detailed balance.

Comment: thanks to your suggestion from Weinberg, I learned that for anti-unit. $A$  if $A|\phi\rangle = |\phi ^{*}\rangle$ then $\langle \phi ^{*} | \psi ^{*}\rangle =\left ( \langle \phi  | \psi \rangle \right)^{*} $ holds. Could you give me some hint how this works, if there is an interaction inbetween $\langle \phi ^{*} | H | \psi ^{*}\rangle$

Comment: @AlexanderCska: The $H$ turns into its conjugate transposed. But your notation is quite irritating and not recommended. One rather interchanges the bras and kets.

Answer (score 3):

Most often, the [$S$-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix) is defined as an operator between asymptotic initial and final Hilbert spaces for a *time-dependent*  scattering process, i.e. between $t\to-\infty$ and $t\to\infty$. There [unitarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarity_%28physics%29) encodes conservation of probabilities over time. On the other hand, the book that OP mentions, Ref. 1, talks about a  *time-independent* scattering process. For a discussion of the connection between time-dependent and time-independent scattering, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12611/2451) Phys.SE question.

In this answer we will only consider time-independent scattering. Ref. 1 defines for a 1D system (divided into three regions $I$, $II$, and $III$, with a localized potential $V(x)$ in the middle region $II$), a $2\times 2$ scattering matrix $S(k)$ as a matrix that tells how two asymptotic incoming (left- and right-moving) waves (of wave number $\mp k$ with $k>0$) are related to two asymptotic outgoing (left- and right-moving) waves. In formulas,

$$\begin{align}\left. \psi(x) \right|_{I}~=~& \underbrace{A(k)e^{ikx}}_{\text{incoming right-mover}} + \underbrace{B(k)e^{-ikx}}_{\text{outgoing left-mover}},  \tag{1} \cr
\left. \psi(x)\right|_{III}~=~& \underbrace{F(k)e^{ikx}}_{\text{outgoing right-mover}} + \underbrace{G(k)e^{-ikx}}_{\text{incoming left-mover}}, \tag{2}\cr
k~>~&0,\end{align}
$$

$$ \begin{pmatrix} B(k) \\ F(k) \end{pmatrix}~=~ S(k) \begin{pmatrix} A(k) \\ G(k) \end{pmatrix}.\tag{3}$$

To show that a finite-dimensional matrix $S(k)$ is [unitary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix), it is enough to show that $S(k)$ is an [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry),

$$\begin{align} S(k)^{\dagger}S(k)~\stackrel{?}{=}~&{\bf 1}_{2\times 2}
\cr\quad\Updownarrow~&\quad\cr
|A(k)|^2+ |G(k)|^2~\stackrel{?}{=}~&|B(k)|^2+ |F(k)|^2,\end{align}\tag{4}$$

or equivalently,

$$ |A(k)|^2-|B(k)|^2 ~\stackrel{?}{=}~|F(k)|^2-|G(k)|^2.\tag{5} $$

Equation (5) can be justified by the following comments and reasoning.

1. $\psi(x)$ is a solution to the time-independent Schrödinger equation ([TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation))
   $$\begin{align} 
   \hat{H} \psi(x) ~=~& E  \psi(x), \cr
   \hat{H}~:=~&\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}+V(x),\cr
   \hat{p}~:=~&\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\end{align}\tag{6}$$
   for positive energy $E>0$.
2. The solution space for the Schrödinger eq. $(6)$, which is a second-order linear ODE, is a two-dimensional vectors space.
3. It follows from eq. $(6)$ that the wave numbers $\pm k$,
   $$k ~:=~\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar} ~\geq~ 0,\tag{7} $$
   must be the same in the two asymptotic regions $I$ and $III$. This will imply that the $M$-matrix (to be defined below) and the $S$-matrix are diagonal in $k$-space.
4. Moreover, it follows that there exists a *bijective linear* map
   $$ \begin{pmatrix} A(k) \\ B(k) \end{pmatrix} ~\mapsto~ \begin{pmatrix} F(k) \\ G(k) \end{pmatrix}.\tag{8}  $$
   In Ref. 2, the *transfer matrix* $M(k)$  is defined as the corresponding matrix
   $$ \begin{pmatrix} F(k) \\ G(k) \end{pmatrix}~=~ M(k) \begin{pmatrix} A(k) \\ B(k) \end{pmatrix}.\tag9$$
   The $S$-matrix $(3)$ is a rearrangement of eq. $(9)$.
5. One may use the Schrödinger eq. $(6)$ (and the reality of  $E$ and $V(x)$) to show that the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) $$ W(\psi,\psi^{\ast})(x)~=~\psi(x)\psi^{\prime}(x)^{\ast}-\psi^{\prime}(x)\psi(x)^{\ast},\tag{10}$$
   or equivalently the [probability current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current)
   $$ J(x)~=~\frac{i\hbar}{2m} W(\psi,\psi^{\ast})(x),\tag{11}$$
   does not depend on the position $x$,
   $$\begin{align} \frac{\mathrm dW(\psi,\psi^*)(x)}{\mathrm dx}
   ~=~&\psi(x)\psi^{\prime\prime}(x)^{\ast}-\psi^{\prime\prime}(x)\psi(x)^{\ast}\cr
   ~\stackrel{(6)}{=}~&0.\end{align}\tag{12}$$
   Unitarity (5) is equivalent to the statement that
   $$\left. W(\psi,\psi^*)\right|_{I}~=~\left. W(\psi,\psi^*) \right|_{III}.\tag{13}$$
   Ref. 3 mentions that eq. $(12)$ encodes conservation of energy in the scattering.

---

References:

1. D.J. Griffiths, *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics;* Section 2.7 in 1st
   edition from 1994 and Problem 2.52 in 2nd edition from 1999.
2. D.J. Griffiths, *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics;* Problem 2.49 in 1st edition from 1994 and Problem 2.53 in 2nd edition from 1999.
3. P.G. Drazin & R.S. Johnson, *Solitons: An Introduction,* 2nd edition, 1989; Section 3.2.

Comment: In this argument, have you used the time-reversal symmetry? I wonder equation 10 is a result of this.

Comment: Hi @an offer can't refuse: Can you elaborate on your reasoning?

Comment: Notes for later: 1. $\hat{H}$ Hermitian $\Rightarrow$ $V$ real $\Rightarrow$ time-reversal symmetry $\Rightarrow$ $S=S^T$ symmetric, cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix#Time-reversal_symmetry). 2. [Optical theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix#Optical_theorem_in_one_dimension): $\quad S=\sigma_x + iT$; $\quad T=\begin{pmatrix} r & t \cr t & s \end{pmatrix}$; $\quad S^{\ast}S={\bf 1}_{2\times 2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad s=r^{\ast}\frac{1+it}{1-it^{\ast}} \quad \wedge \quad 2{\rm Im}(t)=|r|^2+|t|^2$.