# Solving a time independent Schrödinger equation with a given potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

I'm trying to rework this old homework problem, and I am having problems arriving at the same solution on the answer sheet:

> *Let $$V(x)=\begin{cases}\infty &\text{ if } x < 0\\ \alpha\delta(x-a) &\text{ if } x \geq 0 \end{cases}$$ where $a$ and $\alpha$ are of the appropriate units.*
>
> *A particle starts out in the well $0 < x < a$, but because of tunneling its wave function gradually leaks out through the delta-function barrier.*
>
> *(a)  Solve the time independent [Schrödinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) for this potential; impose appropriate boundary conditions, and determine the energy $E$.  An implicit equation will do.*

Here is what I know:

$$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx} &\text{ if } 0 \leq x \leq a\\ Fe^{ikx} &\text{ if } x > a \end{cases}.$$

$\psi(0)=A+B$ and this implies $-A=B$.  I also understand that $\psi$ is continuous at $a$.  What I am stuck on is why $\psi'(a)$ is discontinuous.  Specifically, why is it that:

$$ikFe^{ika}-ikA(e^{ika}+e^{-ika})=\frac{2m\alpha}{\hbar^2}\psi(a).$$

Comment: Hint: Consider integrating the Schrödinger equation over an infinitesimal region about $x=a$ ($x\in [a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$).

Comment: It becomes something like: $\Delta\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)=\frac{-2ma}{\hbar^2}\psi(a)$.  I'm wondering why that negative sign disappears.

Comment: What is $\Delta$? Try again. Integrate $\int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon} dx \left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi(x)}{\partial x^2}+V(x)\psi(x)\right] = \int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon} dx E\psi(x)$, in the limit as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, what do you get? Do not input an explicit $\psi(x)$.

Comment: Right.  So $\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d\psi^2}{dx^2}+\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} V(x)\psi(x)=0$.  Then $\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon}\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d\psi^2}{dx^2}=-\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} V(x)\psi(x)$.  The right hand side becomes $\frac{2ma}{\hbar^2}\psi(a)$.  The left hand side becomes $\frac{d\psi}{dx}\bigg|_{a+\epsilon}-\frac{d\psi}{dx}\bigg|_{a-\epsilon}$.  I'm a bit rusty with all this stuff.

Comment: Ah right sorry yes, that's what you meant by $\Delta$, and you've fixed your minus sign issue. So now you see why it is discontinuous :)

Comment: Not really.  To me, it seems like it would be continuous.

Comment: But you have just shown that the Schrödinger equation requires the derivative of the  wavefunction to not be continuous at $x=a$.

Comment: @Will That is the standard approach. Please consider turning your comments into an answer.

Comment: @Ali at your request, I have posted a solution.

Comment: Another homework question about the same potential: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37857/2451

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note: I have tried to make my answer a little more general, with detail, so that it will be useful for more people.*

---

The question is **what boundary conditions do we apply to our wavefunction either side of a Dirac delta function?**

In your example we have the potential $$V(x)=\begin{cases}\infty &\text{ if } x < 0\\ \alpha~\delta(x-a) &\text{ if } x \geq 0 \end{cases}$$ We are interested in the boundary conditions either side of $x=a$. What information do we have? Well, due to the **probabilistic interpretation** of the wavefunction we require **continuity** of the wavefunction. That is, our first boundary condition is
$$(1)~~~~~~~~~~~~\boxed{\psi_{-}(a) = \psi_{+}(a)}$$
where the $\pm$ subscripts represent the right and left sides of $x=a$ respectively. What other conditions can we set? Well, usually we would ask that the **first derivative** is also matched either side of $x=a$ (you should be asking yourself *why do we do this?*), but in this case this is **not** the right condition to impose. Let's see **why**.

---

**Where does the boundary condition on $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$ come from?**

Our wavefunction is a solution to the 1-D *time-independent* **Schrödinger Equation**:
$$H~\psi(x) = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(x)+V(x)\psi(x) = E~\psi(x)$$
Looking at this equation, we see that we can get a boundary condition on $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$ at any point $a$ by integrating it w.r.t $x$ over the region $[a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]$, taking $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$:
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\left[-\int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}dx\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(x)+\int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}dx~V(x)\psi(x)\right] =  E~\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}~\int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}dx~\psi(x)\\
\implies -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left[\frac{\partial \psi_{+}(a)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial \psi_{-}(a)}{\partial x}\right] + \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}dx~V(x)\psi(x) = 0$$
where we have used the continuity of $\psi$ to evaluate the RHS as zero. Note that for *any* $V(x)$ the second term doesn't necessarily vanish. But, if $V(x)$ is **continuous**, this term will vanish for the same reason the RHS did, and in those cases we yield the usual boundary condition $$\boxed{\frac{\partial \psi_{+}(a)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \psi_{-}(a)}{\partial x}}~~~~~~~(\mbox{when $V(a)$ is continuous at $x=a$})$$
We note that the for example given here, $V(x)$ is definitely **not** continuous at $x=a$, where it diverges to infinity. So this second term doesn't vanish, in fact
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}dx~V(x)\psi(x) = \alpha\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int^{a+\epsilon}_{a-\epsilon}dx~\delta(x-a)\psi(x) = \alpha~\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}~\psi(a) = \alpha~\psi(a)$$
so rearranging our results, the second boundary condition for the problem is
$$(2)~~~~~~~~~~~~\boxed{\frac{\partial \psi_{+}(a)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial \psi_{-}(a)}{\partial x} = \frac{2m\alpha}{\hbar^2}\psi(a)}$$

---

Explicitly using the form of your wavefunctions (using $B=-A$ to eliminate $B$)
$$\psi_{+}(x) = Fe^{ikx},~~~~~~\psi_{-}(x) = A\left(e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}\right)$$
this boundary condition becomes
$$\boxed{ikFe^{ika}-ik\left(Ae^{ika}+e^{-ika}\right) = \frac{2m\alpha}{\hbar^2}\psi(a)}$$
as required.

Comment: This answer (v1) is beautifully written and formatted, so I think we should eventually make an exemption this one time around and allow this full homework answer. But in accordance with our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714), I'm temporarily deleting this.