# Landau & Lifshitz's Approach (contour method) on the WKB connection formulas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, semiclassical, analyticity

Background of the question (see pp. 161, section 47 in Landau & Lifshitz's quantum mechanics textbook Vol3, 2nd Ed. Pergamon Press).
We have the following potential well
$$U(x)\leq E \quad\text{for} \quad x \leq a ,$$
$$U(x)>E \quad\text{for} \quad x>a .\tag{47.0}$$

The WKB solutions right and left to the turning point are

$$\begin{align}\psi=&\dfrac{C}{2\sqrt{p}}\exp{\left(-\dfrac{1}{\hbar}\left|\int_a^x pdx\right|\right)} \cr
&\quad \text{for} \quad x>a, \end{align}  \tag{47.1}$$

$$\begin{align} \psi= & \dfrac{C_1}{\sqrt{p}}\exp{\left(\dfrac{i}{\hbar}\int_a^x pdx\right)}\cr
+&\dfrac{C_2}{\sqrt{p}}\exp{\left(-\dfrac{i}{\hbar}\int_a^x p dx\right)}\cr
&\quad \text{for} \quad x<a,\end{align} \tag{47.2}$$

respectively. Most quantum mechanics textbooks determine the relation between $C$ and $C_i$'s by finding the exact solution near the turning point. And then let the exact solution match with the WKB solutions.

However, in Landau & Lifshitz's quantum mechanics textbooks (vol3, section 47) they let $x$ vary in the complex plane and pass around the turning point $a$ from right to left through a large semicircle in the upper complex plane. Landau claims starting from +$\infty$, when arriving at $-\infty$ (left to $a$), there is phase gain $\pi$ in the denominator of prefactor in Eq.(2). From this we can determine $$C_2=\frac{C}{2}\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{4}\right).\tag{47.4a}$$

They also claim the first term will exponentially decay along the semicircle in the upper half plane. Question is why? Can we show
$$\Im{\left(\int_a^x pdx\right)},$$ where $\Im$ stands for the imaginary part, is positive?

Answer (score 7):

I) L&L are referring to a linearized model where the [TISE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)

$$\begin{align} \hbar^2\psi^{\prime\prime}(x) +P^2(x) \psi(x)~=~&0,\cr  P(x)~:=~ \sqrt{2m (E-V(x))}~=~& |P(x)| e^{i\theta(x)}, \end{align} \tag{1}$$

becomes the [Airy differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html). Near a turning point $x_0$, we can approximate the square momentum

$$\begin{align} P^2(x)~\approx~& \alpha (x\!-\!x_0), \cr (P^2)^{\prime}(x)~\approx~&\alpha~=~2mF_0 ~\neq~0,\end{align}  \tag{2} $$

with an [affine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), where $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ is a non-zero real constant. (In L&L's example $\alpha < 0$ is negative).

II) Let us first reproduce L&L's argument. In the classically allowed region $x<x_0$, L&L choose the momentum $P^{>}>0$ positive. (The superscripts $>$ and $<$ refer to the classically allowed and forbidden regions, respectively.) Hence the WKB wave function (47.2) becomes

$$\begin{align} \psi^{>}~\stackrel{(47.2)}{=}&~\frac{1}{\sqrt{P^{>}}}\sum_{\pm}C_{\pm} \exp\left(\pm \frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{x_0}^x \! P^{>}~\mathrm{d}x\right) \cr
~=~&\frac{1}{\sqrt{|P|}} \sum_{\pm}C_{\pm} \exp\left( \mp \frac{2i\sqrt{|\alpha|}}{3\hbar}\left(x_0-x \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\cr 
& \qquad\text{for}\qquad x<x_0.\end{align}\tag{3}$$

III) L&L is next [analytically continuing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) the WKB wave function (47.1) (which is valid in the classically forbidden region) along an (upper/lower) semicircle in the complex $x$-plane

$$ x-x_0~=~\rho e^{\pm i\phi} , \qquad \phi~\in~[0,\pi], \tag{47.4a}$$

in order to derive the [WKB connection formulas](http://www.google.com/search?&as_q=wkb+connection+formulas).
L&L choose the momentum variable

$$\begin{align} P^{<}~=~&\sqrt{|\alpha|(x-x_0)}\cr
~=~&\sqrt{|\alpha|}\rho^{\frac{1}{2}}  e^{\pm\frac{ i\phi}{2}}, \qquad \rho~>~0,\end{align}\tag{4} $$

such that it starts out positive

$$ \left. P^{<}\right|_{\phi=0}
~=~|P|~>~0. \tag{5} $$

The analytical continuation of the WKB wave function (47.1) then becomes

$$\begin{align} \psi^{<}~\stackrel{(47.1)}{=}&~\frac{C}{2\sqrt{P^{<}}} \exp\left( -\frac{1}{\hbar}\int_{x_0}^x \! P^{<}~\mathrm{d}x\right)\cr
~=~&\frac{C}{2\sqrt{|P|}} \exp\left( -\frac{2\sqrt{|\alpha|}\rho^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{\pm\frac{ i3\phi}{2}} }{3\hbar} \mp i\frac{\phi}{4}\right). 
\end{align}\tag{6} $$

By setting $\phi=\pi$ in eq. (6), and comparing with the WKB wave function (3), one deduces from the analytical continuation along the (upper/lower) semicircle that

$$\begin{align} C_2~\equiv~& C_-~=~\frac{C}{2}e^{-\frac{i\pi}{4}}, \tag{47.4b}\cr
C_1~\equiv~& C_+~=~\frac{C}{2}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}} , \tag{47.4c}\end{align} $$

respectively. This is L&L's main argument. (We will return to the question of what happens to the other branch in Section VII below.)

IV) Alternatively, since the [Airy functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) have Fourier integral representations (cf. e.g. my Math.SE answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1963893/11127)), one may instead use the [method of steepest descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent) to derive matching asymptotic expansions on each side of the turning point. It is interesting to compare this method with L&L's above argument.

One may show that the Airy-like wave function

$$ \psi(x) ~=~ \sqrt{\frac{|\alpha|}{\pi\hbar}}\int_{\mathbb{R}-i~{\rm sgn}(\alpha)~\varepsilon} \! \mathrm{d}p~ 
\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S(p,x)\right),\tag{7}$$
$$\begin{align} S(p,x)~:=~& px  - \tilde{S}(p),  \cr
\tilde{S}(p)~:=~& p\left(x_0+\frac{p^2}{3\alpha}\right),\end{align} \tag{8}$$
$$\begin{align} S^{\prime}(p,x)~=~&x-\tilde{S}^{\prime}(p)\cr ~=~& x\!-\!x_0 - \frac{p^2}{\alpha}\cr ~\stackrel{(2)}{\approx}~& \frac{P^2(x)-p^2}{\alpha},\end{align} \tag{9} $$
$$-S^{\prime\prime}(p,x)~=~\tilde{S}^{\prime\prime}(p)~=~ \frac{2p}{\alpha},\tag{10}  $$

satisfies the TISE (1):

$$\begin{align} \hbar^2& \psi^{\prime\prime}(x) +P^2(x)  \psi(x)\cr
~\stackrel{(7)}{=}~& 
\sqrt{\frac{|\alpha|}{\pi\hbar}}
\int_{\mathbb{R}-i~{\rm sgn}(\alpha)~\varepsilon} \! \mathrm{d}p~\left(P^2(x)- p^2\right) \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S(p,x)\right)\cr
~\stackrel{(9)}{\approx}~&
-i \hbar \alpha\sqrt{\frac{|\alpha|}{\pi\hbar}}
\int_{\mathbb{R}-i~{\rm sgn}(\alpha)~\varepsilon} \! \mathrm{d}p~\frac{d}{dp}  \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S(p,x)\right)\cr
~=~&0 \end{align}\tag{11}$$

for the chosen contour in the complex $p$-plane.

V) There are 2 critical points:

$$\begin{align} p_{\sigma} ~=~& \sigma~ {\rm sgn}(\alpha)~P   , \cr 
S_{\sigma}~=~& \frac{2\sigma P^3 }{3|\alpha|}  , \cr 
S^{\prime\prime}_{\sigma}~=~&  -2\sigma |\alpha| P  , \cr 
\sigma ~\in~&\{\pm 1\}.\end{align} \tag{12}$$

The steepest descent contribution from each critical point comes from a [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral):

$$\begin{align} I_{\sigma}~=~& \sqrt{\frac{|\alpha|}{\pi\hbar}} \sqrt{\frac{2\pi i\hbar}{S^{\prime\prime}_{\sigma} } }  \exp\left(\frac{i S_{\sigma}}{\hbar}\right)\cr
~=~&\frac{1}{\sqrt{P}} \exp\left(\frac{2i\sigma P^3}{3\hbar |\alpha|} -\frac{i\sigma \pi}{4}\right)\cr
~=~& \frac{1}{\sqrt{|P|}} \exp\left(\frac{2i\sigma |P|^3e^{3i\theta}}{3\hbar |\alpha|} -i\left(\frac{\sigma \pi}{4}+\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right) \end{align} \tag{13} $$

with angular steepest descent direction $-\frac{\sigma \pi}{4}-\frac{\theta}{2}$.

[image]

$\uparrow$ Fig. 1. The complex $p$-plane with 3 possible integration contours ${\cal C}_1$, ${\cal C}_2$, ${\cal C}_3$ for $\alpha<0$. The shaded regions denote exponentially decaying sectors. (If $\alpha>0$, it is opposite.) Since the integrand is an [entire function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) in $p$, the $p$-integral only depend on the [monodromy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy) of the contour. (Figure taken from Ref. [W].)

VI) Now let us return to L&L's example with $\alpha<0$.

*Classically forbidden region $x>x_0$:* Then $P=\pm i|P|$, with $\theta=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$, where $\pm$ corresponds to two different possible sign choices. The contour along the real $p$-axis is reproduced by the steepest descent contour corresponding to the critical point $p_{\mp 1}$:

$$\begin{align} \psi_{<}(x)~\sim~&  I_{\mp 1}\cr
~=~& \frac{1}{\sqrt{|P|}} \exp\left(-\frac{2|P|^3}{3\hbar |\alpha|} \right). \end{align} \tag{14} $$

*Classically allowed region $x<x_0$:* Then $P=|P|>0$ with $\theta=0$. The contour along the real $p$-axis is reproduced by the sum of both steepest descent contours:

$$\begin{align} \psi_{>}(x)~\sim~& \sum_{\sigma\in\{\pm 1\}}I_{\sigma}\cr
~=~& \frac{1}{\sqrt{|P|}}\sum_{\sigma\in\{\pm 1\}} \exp\left(i\sigma\left(\frac{2|P|^3}{3\hbar |\alpha|} -\frac{ \pi}{4}\right)\right)\cr
~=~&\frac{2}{\sqrt{|P|}} \cos\left(\frac{2|P|^3}{3\hbar |\alpha|} -\frac{\pi}{4} \right)\cr
~=~& \frac{2}{\sqrt{|P|}} \sin\left(\frac{2|P|^3}{3\hbar |\alpha|} +\frac{\pi}{4} \right).\end{align} \tag{15} $$

By comparing eqs. (14) & (15), we have derived a connection formula. In detail, by comparing the contributions to the critical points $p_{\mp 1}$, we deduce L&L's eqs. (47.4c) and (47.4b), respectively. So the two methods agree.

VII) Exponentially growing solutions are physically possible if the classically forbidden region has finite length, e.g. in quantum tunneling. However, in L&L's example, the classically forbidden region is non-compact, so exponentially growing solutions must be discarded.

It remains to explain why only one of the 2 oscillatory branches in the classically allowed side gets analytically continued to the classically forbidden side.

On one hand, L&L argue that the exponentially growing WKB branch cannot be trusted during the $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ phase shift in the Boltzmann factor because it becomes momentarily exponentially suppressed. This highlights the fact that the connection formulas are one-directional.

On the other hand, from the perspective of the method of steepest descent in Sections IV-VI, one crosses a [Stokes line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_phenomenon) in the complex $x$-plane, so that the steepest descent contours pick up monodromy in the complex $p$-plane, cf. Fig. 1.

For more information, see also e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/192170/2451).

VIII) Finally, we should mention that the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ phase shift between the incoming and outgoing wave at the turning point in eq. (15) corresponds to a [Maslov index](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Maslov+index) $|\mu|=1$,
cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146130/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

- [LL] L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *QM,* Vol. 3, [2nd](https://archive.org/details/ost-physics-landaulifshitz-quantummechanics) & 3rd ed, 1981; $\S47$ & $\S b$.
- [W] E. Witten, *Analytic Continuation Of Chern-Simons Theory,* [arXiv:1001.2933](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.2933); p. 23-29, 48-49. A related 2015 KITP lecture by Witten, *A New Look At The Path Integral Of Quantum Mechanics,* can be found on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOz6e5rmnjQ).

Comment: L&L propose to go backwards from $\pi$ to $0$ in the plane $y>0$.  Then $\frac{c_2}{\sqrt{p}}e^{-i\int p(x)dx}$ becomes small. To make the term $\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{p}}e^{+i\int p(x)dx}$, small one has to do the same for $y<0$.   Could you please comment how one could possibly deduce this by looking at $\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{p}}e^{+i\int p(x)dx}+\frac{c_2}{\sqrt{p}}e^{-i\int p(x)dx}$. I don't see how the formula $x-a=\rho e^{i\phi}$ is applied here, if applied at all. I don't really get it from your answer. thank you in advance

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I plan to review this in the near future.

Comment: I gave it a little taught. I think that this is quite simple, as Landau himself writes. If one would continue $\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{p(x)}}e^{i\int p(x)dx}$ in the complex plane via $x-a=\rho e^{i\phi}$ one gets $e^{-\sin{\frac{3\phi}{2}}+i \cos{\frac{3\phi}{2}}}$.  The same can be done for $\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{p(x)}}e^{-i\int p(x)dx}=e^{+\sin{\frac{3\phi}{2}}-i \cos{\frac{3\phi}{2}}}$. The sum of these two terms would give the desired result if one would go from $0,2\pi$ or backwards $2\pi,0$.