# When is a logarithm of the wavefunction well-defined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, semiclassical

It is sometimes convenient to write the wavefunction as
$$
\Psi(x,t)~=~ e^{\Phi(x,t)}
$$
and then work with $\Phi$ instead. This is particularly sensible in the context of the WKB approximation, where $\Phi$ is nice a smooth and slowly changing.

But, does $\Phi$ exist in general? There's a reason it might not. Let's say that $\Psi(x_0,t_0) = 0$. It could be that, near $(x,t) = (x_0,t_0)$, the wavefunction looks like

$$
\Psi(x,t) = e^{i \tan^{-1} \frac{x-x_0}{t-t_0}}
\text.
$$

(When I write $\tan^{-1}$, I mean something like the C/python "atan2" function. It's just the angle formed by the vector $(x-x_0,t-t_0)$. I hope that's clear.)

So, this wavefunction is smooth and well-behaved at $(x_0,t_0)$, but the imaginary part of its logarithm can't be consistently defined. I guess one could say that $\Phi(x,t)$ has a branch point.

Obviously this can't happen if there wavefunction never vanishes. The only place where I know I can guarantee $\Psi \ne 0$ is the ground state of a bosonic system. Are there other situations in which $\Phi$ can be guaranteed to make sense?

(For that matter... does $\Phi$ have a name?)

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, concerning the 1D [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation), the WKB wave function
$$\psi(x) ~\sim~\frac{1}{\sqrt{p(x)}}\sum_{\pm}C_{\pm} \exp\left(\pm \frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{x_0}^x \! p(x)~\mathrm{d}x\right)$$
typically becomes singular near turning points, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281816/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Another example: $n=2$ states of hydrogen. There's always a zero of $\Psi$, but depending on $\ell,m$, $\Phi$ can either be well defined or not.