# Degeneracy of energy eigenstates when $E > V$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, s-matrix-theory

Reading my text book on quantum physics, I found the following statement:

Let's suppose we have a short-scale force, so we have a potential energy such that
$$
V(x) = V_- \quad \text{if} \quad x \ll 0 \\
V(x) = V_+ \quad\text{if}\quad x \gg 0
$$
with $V_+ \ge V_-$, the wavefunction on these regions is
$$
\Phi_E = A e^{ik_-x} + B e^{-ik_-x} \quad\text{if}\quad x \ll 0 \qquad \text{with}\quad k_- = \sqrt{2m(E-V_-)}/\hbar \\
\Phi_E = C e^{ik_+x} + D e^{-ik_+x} \quad\text{if}\quad x \gg 0 \qquad \text{with}\quad k_+ = \sqrt{2m(E-V_+)}/\hbar
$$
**Since there exist a linear relationship between $\Phi_E(x\ll 0)$ and $\Phi_E(x\gg 0)$, the coefficients also have a linear relationship**
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}A\\B\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}t_{11}&t_{12}\\t_{21}&t_{22}\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}C\\D\end{array}\right)
$$
**and only two coefficients are indepent. Thus, all the energies $E>V_+$ have a multiplicity of two.**

I understand that the degeneracy must be two because of the two independent coefficients, but I don't see where the linear relationship between $\Phi_E(x\ll 0)$ and $\Phi_E(x\gg 0)$ comes from to explain this result. Is there any easy proof of this?

Comment: Which textbook? Which page?

Answer (score 0):

1. The point is that the 1D [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) for fixed energy $E>V_{\pm}$ is a 2nd-order linear homogeneous ODE. We assume that the solutions are **globally** well-defined on the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$. So the general solution $\psi$ is a complex linear combination of 2 linearly independent solutions $\psi_{1/2}$.
2. We next choose $\psi_{1/2}$ such that they satisfy the boundary condition
   $$ \lim_{x\to \infty}e^{(-1)^a ik_+ x}\psi_a(x)~=~1, \qquad a~\in~\{1,2\}.$$
   Note that $\psi_1$ corresponds to $(C,D)=(1,0)$ while  $\psi_2$ corresponds to $(C,D)=(0,1)$.
3. We finally define the transfer matrix elements as
   $$\psi_a(x)~\sim~t_{1a}e^{ ik_- x}+t_{2a}e^{ -ik_- x}
    \quad{\rm for}\quad x\to -\infty.$$
   Note that $\psi_1$ corresponds to $(A,B)=(t_{11},t_{21})$ while  $\psi_2$ corresponds to $(A,B)=(t_{12},t_{22})$.
4. This explains the linear relationship between $(C,D)$ and $(A,B)$. See also e.g. my related Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/21977/2451).