# Scattering on delta function potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, potential, scattering

Suppose a particle has energy $E>V(+/-\infty)=0$, then the solutions to the Schrodinger equation outside of the potential will be $\psi(x)=Ae^{i k x}+Be^{-i k x}$.
How can one show or explain that $|B|/|A|$ gives the probability that a particle scattering off the potential is reflected?

Comment: You can either argue with probability currents (though this was always confusing to me). The nice way is to construct wave-packets with the scattering solutions of a small range of momenta and then calculate what is the probability of the particle to be scattered.

Comment: Can you explain more? If I start with a gaussian wavepacket, how do I get it to travel? If I apply the schrodinger equation to find its time evolution, it just stays at the same point but flattens out, how can I input its initial speed?

Comment: @Hobo: work with the momentum first.  Try something like $\int dk A\,e^{-\alpha k^{2}}e^{-i\beta kx}$, with $A, \alpha,$ and $\beta$ constant.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/why-can-we-treat-quantum-scattering-problems-as-time-independent?rq=1

Comment: @jjcale: voted to close as duplicate, I can't see how to answer without replicating the answer to the previous question verbatim.