# "Synchronization" Probability of Multiple Waves with Varying Frequencies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, frequency, probability, signal-processing, coherence

Update 1: I've done some digging and I think this is related to signal coherence, namely, that I'm seeing a coherence time of ~3 σ, which is consistent with the definition where Ct=1/Δv where Δv is the bandwidth of a signal. I've approximated the bandwith of my ensemble of signals being ~3 σ which encapsulates 99% of possible period values.

I have a question that appears to be related to the beat frequencies of multiple oscillatory signals. Suppose I have $n$ number of sinusoidal waves, each of which follow
$ sin(2 \pi \frac1\tau t+\phi)$ and imagine that we add a variability to the frequency, such that $\tau$~$N(\tau,\sigma^2)$.

At time $t=0$, all $n$ waves will be in-phase, following a divergence to out-phase and, depending on the number of waves and their difference in frequencies, a return to in-phase.

I've ran a couple of simulation in an attempt to gain some insight into how the number of oscillatory signals and the magnitude of noise in $\tau$ affects the capacity for the a population of signals to eventually reach a state in which they are in-phase.

I visualized the degree of "in-phase"ness of a population of signals by summing the signals' amplitudes (highest absolute value of the sum should indicate phase matching).

The sum of 2 signals with  $\tau$~$N(\pi,.07\pi)$
[image]
The sum of 100 signals with  $\tau$~$N(\pi,.07\pi)$
[image]
The sum of 500 signals with  $\tau$~$N(\pi,.07\pi)$
[image]

I also varied $\tau's$ noise as:

The sum of 100 signals with  $\tau$~$N(\pi,.14\pi)$
[image]
The sum of 100 signals with  $\tau$~$N(\pi,.3\pi)$
[image]

So my question is has anyone encountered any theory related to the apparent phenomenon where there seems to be an exponential convergence to a state of asynchronous that is dependent on the number of signals being considered? Also, the magnitude of the noise of the frequencies seems to dampen the approach to asynchrony.

I saw hints of an answer [in this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60343/why-does-the-wave-description-say-that-probability-oscillates-while-the-phase-i) which is why I've added the quantum mechanics tag as the knowledge of dealing with adding waves of probabilities is probably useful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've done some digging and I think this is related to signal coherence, namely, that I'm seeing a coherence time of ~3 $\sigma$, which is consistent with the definition where $C_t = 1/\Delta v$ where $\Delta v$ is the bandwidth of a signal. I've approximated the bandwith of my ensemble of signals being ~3 $\sigma$ which encapsulates 99% of possible period values. Anyone know of a good resource in deriving coherence time and how it relates to the number of signals being considered?