# Are all bound states normalizeable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, definition

Following Griffiths eq. (2.91) on p. 52 one may define a bound state to be an energy eigenstate
$$H|E\rangle=E|E\rangle\tag{1}$$
with an energy being smaller than the potential far away from the origin in the sense
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty} V(x)>E.\tag{2}$$
Intuitively we want bound states $|E\rangle$ to be states with a finite spread in position space and to be normalizeable. This means the probability density $|\langle x|E\rangle|^2=|\psi_E(x)|^2$ should vanish at infinity. Is the requirement (2) enough to guarantee this? This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_state#Position-bound_states) claims this.

Their reasoning seems flawed to me though: Rewriting eq. (1) in position basis
$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi_E''(x)=\left(V(x)-E\right)\psi_E(x) \tag{3}$$
they directly deduce that $\psi_E(x)$ must decay exponentially for large $x$ as $V(x)-E\gt 0$ for all $x$ bigger than some $X$.

I fail so see why this is true.

So let me expand my question - What really are [bound states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_state) by definition? Griffiths approach seems to be a too weak condition.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a bound states is defined as a localized state, period - because that's the experimental observation you want to describe. Then, you have to ask if the condition $\tilde V(x)>E$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$ fulfills this definition. I think the latter is a purely mathematical argument that imposes some condition on $\tilde V(x)$ (e.g. differentiable) and involves a little calculus and limit arithmetic so that the exponential decay can be proven mathematicaly. I'm not feeling savvy enough with limits to stand behind such a calculation if I did it myself. Maybe someone else is?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68639/2451 and links therein.

Comment: [Related?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350394/85443)

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR: OP has a point. Griffiths' bound state condition
$$E~<~ V(\pm\infty) \tag{2.91} $$
on p. 52 is incomplete. The solution $\psi$ to the 1D [TISE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) will be a linear combination of exponentially growing and exponentially damped solutions in the asymptotic regions.
One needs to impose an extra condition to get rid of the non-normalizable exponentially growing solution. A heavy-handed (although standard) condition (which Griffiths presumably implicitly has in mind) would be to declare that $\psi$ should be normalizable from the onset. However, it turns out that it is enough to e.g. impose an asymptotic bound (C) on $\psi$, cf. the following Theorem.

> *Theorem.* Let there be given the 1D TISE
> $$\psi^{\prime\prime}(x)~=~\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V(x)-E)\psi(x). \tag{A}$$
> If$^1$
> $$ \exists k,K>0\forall |x|\geq K:~~ {\rm Re}\left[\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V(x)-E)\right]  ~\geq~ k^2,\tag{B}$$
> and if $\psi$ is asymptotically bounded
> $$ \exists c,K>0\forall |x|\geq K:~~ |\psi(x)|~\leq ~c,\tag{C} $$
> then $\psi$ is exponentially damped:
> $$\exists C>0 \forall |x|\geq K:~~ |\psi(x)| ~\leq~Ce^{-k|x|}, \tag{D} $$
> and hence normalizable/square integrable.

*Sketched proof of Theorem:*

1. From fairly mild assumptions about the potential $V$, we may assume that the solution $\psi$ is sufficiently many times differentiable, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19715/2451).
2. Let us use polar decomposition
   $$ \psi(x)~=~R(x)e^{i\Theta(x)}. \tag{E} $$
   Note that the function $R$ might not be differentiable at its zeros $R(x)=0$, although $R=|\psi|$ is still continuous everywhere.
3. For $|x|\geq K$ away from the zeros $R(x)\neq 0$, we calculate:
   $$\begin{align} \frac{R^{\prime\prime}(x)}{R(x)}~\geq~&\frac{R^{\prime\prime}(x)-R(x)\Theta^{\prime}(x)^2}{R(x)}\cr
   ~\stackrel{(E)}{=}~&{\rm Re}\frac{\psi^{\prime\prime}(x)}{\psi(x)}\cr
   ~\stackrel{(A)}{=}~&{\rm Re}\left[\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}(V(x)-E)\right]\cr
   ~\stackrel{(B)}{\geq}~& k^2. \end{align}
   \tag{F} $$
   So $R$ is [concave upward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), $R^{\prime\prime}>0$.
4. It follows that $R$ can not have more than 1 zero in each of the asymptotic regions $]-\infty,-K]$ and $[K,\infty[$. By possibly choosing a bigger $K>0$, we may assume that there are no zeros in the asymptotic regions:
   $$\forall |x|\geq K:~~ \psi(x)\neq 0. \tag{G}$$
5. Together with the bounds (C), $R^{\prime\prime}>0$ means that
   $$\begin{align} 
   \forall x\geq K:~~ R^{\prime}(x)~\leq~& 0,\cr
   \forall x\leq -K:~~ R^{\prime}(x)~\geq~& 0. \end{align}\tag{H}$$
6. Let us define
   $$S(x)~:=~\ln R(x). \tag{I} $$
   Eq. (H) becomes
   $$\begin{align} 
   \forall x\geq K:~~ S^{\prime}(x)~\leq~& 0,\cr
   \forall x\leq -K:~~ S^{\prime}(x)~\geq~& 0. \end{align}\tag{J}$$
   Eq. (F) transforms into a [Riccati inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation):
   $$\forall |x|\geq K:~~ 
   S^{\prime\prime}(x) +S^{\prime}(x)^2~\geq~ k^2.\tag{K} $$
7. One may now show that
   $$\begin{align} 
   \forall x\geq K:~~ S^{\prime}(x)~\leq~& -k,\cr
   \forall x\leq -K:~~ S^{\prime}(x)~\geq~& k. \end{align}\tag{L}$$
   Indirect proof of eq. (L): Assume the opposite:
   $$\begin{align} 
   \exists x_1\geq K:~~ S^{\prime}(x_1)~>~& -k,\cr
   \exists x_1\leq -K:~~ S^{\prime}(x_1)~<~& k. \end{align}\tag{M}$$
   Then we may rewrite the Riccati ineq. (K) as
   $$
   \frac{1}{k}\frac{d}{dx}{\rm artanh}\frac{S^{\prime}(x)}{k} ~=~\frac{S^{\prime\prime}(x)}{k^2-S^{\prime}(x)^2} ~\stackrel{(K)}{\geq}~ 1\tag{N} $$
   in a neighborhood of $x_1$. In particular we note that  $S^{\prime\prime}(x)>0$, i.e. $S^{\prime}$ is an increasing function. Therefore, in the 2 cases of eq. (M), we may let $x_1\to\pm\infty$, respectively, without violating eq. (M). Integration of ineq. (N) leads to
   $$
   {\rm artanh}\frac{S^{\prime}(x)}{k} 
   ~\left\{\begin{array}{c}\geq\cr\leq\end{array}\right\}~ k(x\!-\!x_0),\tag{O} $$
   or equivalently,
   $$S^{\prime}(x)
   ~\left\{\begin{array}{c}\geq\cr\leq\end{array}\right\}~
   k\tanh k(x\!-\!x_0),\tag{P} $$
   in a neighborhood of $x_1$ in the 2 cases, respectively.
   However, ineq. (P) would violate ineq. (J) in the limit $x\to\pm\infty$, respectively. Contradiction. Hence ineq. (L) holds.
8. Integration of ineq. (L) leads to
   $$ \forall |x|\geq K\exists C>0:~~ S(x) ~\leq~-k|x|+\ln C. \tag{Q} $$
   Now apply the exponential function on each side of the ineq. (Q) to derive the sought-for ineq. (D). $\Box$

--

$^1$ We allow $V(x)-E$ to be complex to include the case of unstable/decaying or [resonant states](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=resonant+states+quantum+mechanics).

Answer (score 5):

I think Griffiths means that we assume that
\begin{equation} \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} V(x) = V_R > E \end{equation}
i.e. that the potential tends to a *constant* value $V_R$ that is larger than $E$. In this case we can prove it as follows:

As OP writes, this means that for some $X_R$ and some $\epsilon > 0$, we have
\begin{equation} | V(x) - V_R | < \epsilon \quad \forall x > X_R \end{equation}
Let us choose $X_R$ large enough so that
\begin{equation} V(x) > E \quad \forall x>X_R \end{equation}
and approximate $V(x)$ by $V_R$ in this region. The error will be $\epsilon$, which we can make as small as we want by choosing $X_R$ large enough (but finite).

In this case, the Schrödinger equation reads
\begin{equation} -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi_E''(x) + V_R \psi_E(x) = E\psi_E(x) \quad \forall x>X_R \end{equation}
which means

\begin{equation} \psi_E''(x) = \frac{2m}{\hbar^2} (V_R - E) \psi_E(x) \quad \forall x>X_R \end{equation}
Since $V_R - E > 0$ by assumption, this is a differential equation with solution
\begin{equation} \psi_E (x) = C_1 \exp \left(x \sqrt{\frac{2m(V_R - E)}{\hbar^2}} \right) + C_2 \left(-x \sqrt{\frac{2m(V_R - E)}{\hbar^2}} \right) \end{equation}
Unless we *want* something non-normalizable, we have to set $C_1 = 0$. The value of $C_2$ must be determined by the value of $\psi_E$ and $\psi_E'$ for $x<X_R$. Hence the wave function decays exponentially. The same analysis obviously holds for negative $x$, just replace $V_R$ by $V_L$, $X_R$ by $X_L$, let $x < X_L$ etc. This is just the particle in a (reeeeeeeeally wide) finite box.

That being the case, the whole wave function is normalizable because the interval $[X_L, X_R]$ is finite and the wave function decays exponentially for $x<X_L$ and $x>X_R$.

For potentials that *don't* have a limit when $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$, e.g. periodic potentials, I don't think we can say much. Periodic potentials are solved by [Bloch's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice) and they would give non-normalizable wave functions if we did not use periodic boundary conditions to study the bulk of the lattice.

Comment: Thank you for this analyisis. This is exactly what I've been doing before, but the thing is in setting $C_2=0$ we assume that we want a normalizeable function. So this doesn't prove that all functions satisfying the "Griffiths condition" are normalizeable or bound in that sense..

Comment: As @KeithMcClary pointed out there are also functions which vanish at infinity and don't fulfill the Griffiths condition. So even the converse isn't true.. I really don't see how the definition of Griffiths is any good then.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that _any_ normalizable wf should be defined as a bound state?? I don't follow (it's getting late where I live, sorry if I'm being dense). I think for a state to be a bound state it must _at least_ be normalizable, and then it must also satisfy the "Griffith condition".

Comment: I mean, if we don't set $C_2 = 0$ then we have bigger problems to worry about than whether the wf is a bound state or not!