# The spectrum of the Hamiltonian in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, wavefunction, mathematical-physics

Consider the Hilbert space $\mathscr{H} = L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and a Hamiltonian:
$$H = -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\Delta + V(x)$$
for some potential function $V$. States of well-defined energy $E$ are obtained by means of the Schrödinger equation:
$$H\psi(x) = -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\Delta\psi(x) + V(x)\psi(x) = E\psi(x). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
With some boundary condition on the function $\psi(x)$. In the physics literature, we often see the following characterization:

- If $E \le \lim_{|x|\to \infty}V(x)$, the solution of (\ref{1}) is called a bound state and the associate eigenvalues that admit nonzero solutions form a *discrete* set.
- If $E > \lim_{|x|\to \infty}V(x)$, the solution of (\ref{1}) is called a scattering state and the associate eigenvalues that admit nonzero solutions form a *continuous* set.

Now, define the *discrete spectrum* of $H$ by:
$$\sigma_{d}(H) := \{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}: \mbox{$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $H$ with finite multiplicity}\}$$
and its *essential spectrum* by $\sigma_{ess}(H) := \sigma(H)\setminus \sigma_{d}(H)$, with $\sigma(H)$ denoting spectrum of $H$. It seems to me that the above two conditions can be translated as:

- A state $\psi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ is a bound state iff $H\psi(x) = E\psi(x)$, with $E \in \sigma_{d}(H)$.
- A state $\psi \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ for $H$ is a scattering state iff $H\psi(x) = E\psi(x)$ with $E \in \sigma_{ess}(H)$.

Hence, it seems that the study of the discrete and essential spectrum of $H$ *completely characterizes its bound and scattering states*.

On the other hand, we can also define the *pure point spectrum* $\sigma_{pp}(H)$, the *absolutely continuous spectrum* $\sigma_{ac}(H)$ and the *singular spectrum* $\sigma_{s}(H)$ of $H$ by means of the [Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)).

In mathematics books, one is usually interested in the characterization of these three spectrum. So, my question is: if the above analysis is correct, what is the point of analyzing these three other spectrum, if all relevant physical information seems to be concentrated on the discrete and essential spectrum? I mean, if I prove that $\sigma_{ac}(H)\cup \sigma_{s}(H) = \emptyset$, then the spectrum of $H$ consists only of eigenvalues and the study of the Schrödinger equation tell us all we need to know about the spectrum of $H$. That's fine to me. But otherwise, what is the physical relevance of $\sigma_{ac}(H)$ and $\sigma_{s}(H)$ when this is *not* the case?

Comment: Not sure how it relates to the differences between the different components of the spectrum, but note [that there is a potential for which a bound state exists with energy *above* the value of $V$ at infinity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350394/83835). I think these correspond to so-called "exceptional points" in the continuum component of the spectrum.

Comment: scattering states are not normalizable, hence cannot be in $L^2$!

Comment: This sort of question may very well be better suited for a StackExchange like Math or MathOverflow. That said, I just want to point out that there are loads of bound states that are formed through arbitrary superpositions of stationary bound states (i.e. a bound or scattering state doesn't need to be an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian as your definitions seem to require).