# What are the exact relations between bound states, discrete spectra, and negative energies in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, scattering, quantum-tunneling

Consider the nonrelativistic quantum mechanics of one particle in one dimension ("NRQMOPOD") with the time-independent Schrodinger equation

$$
\left( -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x) \right) \psi(x) = E\ \psi(x),
$$
where we assume that the potential energy function $V(x)$ is continuous and at large distances approaches a constant value
$$
V_\infty = \lim_{|x| \to \infty} V(x)
$$
in the extended real line (which is often set to 0 if $V_\infty$ is finite). We do not assume that the eigenfunction $\psi(x)$ is necessarily normalizable.

"Folk wisdom" says that the following three statements are equivalent:

1. $\psi(x)$ is normalizable, i.e. $$\int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx\ |\psi(x)|^2 < \infty.$$ Or equivalently, $\psi(x)$ represents a bound state, i.e. $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int \limits_{|x| > R} dx\ |\psi(x)|^2 = 0.$$ (The equivalence of these two statements is a straightforward exercise in real analysis.)
2. $E < V_\infty$, and
3. $E$ lies in a discrete part of the energy spectrum, i.e. there exists a proper energy interval such that $E$ is the only eigenvalue in the Hamiltonian's spectrum that lies within that interval.

But this folk wisdom is incorrect. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350394/92058) gives an explicit example of a potential energy function $V(x)$ and a normalizable energy eigenstate $\psi(x)$ with energy $E > V_\infty$. Therefore, statement #1 above does not imply statement #2. (I do not know whether the spectrum for the particular Hamiltonian given in that example is discrete or continuous around the relevant eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, so I don't know the status of claim #3 for this example.)

What are the exact implications between the three statements above?
Of the six possible implications, which have been proven to be true, which have explicit known counterexamples, and which are still open problems?

I'd also like to know about the case of multiple spatial dimensions, although I assume that the answers are probably the same as for the 1D case.

Comment: Are you considering $\psi(x)$ to be an eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian ?

Comment: @Mauricio Yes, as implied by the first equation.

Comment: You are asking this in the wrong forum. I would suggest to ask mathematicians who are working on spectral problems for such operators.

Comment: Just to add some jargon: the phenomenon of bound states with $E>V_\infty$ has become known as bound states in the continuum. The old example by von Neumann and Wigner is not the only one anymore, although practical studies are mostly for wave equations encountered in optics/photonics (see e.g. https://www.nature.com/articles/natrevmats201648).

Comment: @Wolpertinger Thanks, that's helpful. This article seems to be discussing states that satisfy #1 but not #3, as opposed to the example in my question that violates #2. Does that mean that statements #2 and #3 are equivalent, but distinct from #1?

Comment: hm, good point… I do not know! I also suspect that this article may only be of limited help for your problem anyway, since Maxwell’s wave and the Schrödinger eqn seem to differ quite significantly in some of their mathematical properties. Eg I‘m not sure whether condition 2 even makes sense for Maxwell (in 1D, you can see it as a Schrödinger eqn where the potential depends on the energy eigenvalue, so $V_\infty$ does too). Condition 1 & 3 seem more generically applicable to differential operators.

Comment: Crossposted to https://mathoverflow.net/q/444183/13917

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to have eigenvalues inside the continuous spectrum. I think the helium atom with no interaction between the electrons is such an example if my memory serves well.

Answer (score 0):

Negative energies become when the particle is unbonded and falls in at least finite potential well.

Stationary waves of finite potential wells for one dimension are available on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well

Here there is already the case of spherical potential well for 3D. In this case the radial part of the wave vanishes when going far because amplitude is well spread at spherical surface as a function of the radius.