# Is it possible to give a perturbative potential to a free particle so that its energy levels are discrete?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

The original system is a free particle, and there are no restrictions on its space.
Assume that the perturbation potential is
$\epsilon \frac{\mu\omega^2}{2} x^2$ so that
$$
\hat{H}=\hat{H}_0+\epsilon\hat{H}'=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\epsilon\frac{\mu\omega^2}{2}x^2\,.
$$
Assume that the wave function of a free particle with momentum $p'$ is
$$\psi_{p'}^0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{ip'x/\hbar}\,.$$

The superscript number indicates the number of perturbation levels.
The first level perturbation fixed state Schrödinger equation is
$$\hat{H}'\psi_{p'}^0+\hat{H}_0\psi_{p'}^1=E^1_{p'}\psi_{p'}^0+E_{p'}^0\psi_{p'}^1$$

If we use the unperturbed perturbation wave function to represent the level 1 perturbation wave function:
$$\psi_{p'}^1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int a_{p'}^1(p)e^{i\frac{p}{\hbar}x} dp$$

After multiplying both sides by the complex conjugate of the unperturbed wave function to integrate over the full space, we can obtain
$$\psi_{p''}^{0*}\hat{H}'\psi_{p'}^0+\psi_{p''}^{0*}\hat{H}_0\psi_{p'}^1=E^1_{p'}\psi_{p''}^{0*}\psi_{p'}^0+E_{p'}^0\psi_{p''}^{0*}\psi_{p'}^1\,,$$
in which case
$$-\frac{\mu\omega^2\hbar^2}{2}\delta''(p'-p'')+E_{p''}^0a_{p'}^1(p'')=E^1_{p'}\delta(p'-p'')+E_{p'}^0a_{p'}^1(p'')$$
and
$$E^1_{p'}\delta(p'-p'')+\frac{\mu\omega^2\hbar^2}{2}\delta''(p'-p'')=(E_{p''}^0-E_{p'}^0)a_{p'}^1(p'')\,.$$

Considering $E^0_{p'}=\frac{p'^2}{2\mu}$, we can obtain
$$E^1_{p'}\delta'(p'-p'')+\frac{\mu\omega^2\hbar^2}{6}\delta^{(3)}(p'-p'')=\frac{p'+p''}{2\mu}a_{p'}^1(p'')$$
so that
$$a_{p'}^1(p'')=E^1_{p'}\frac{2\mu}{p'+p''}\delta'(p'-p'')+\frac{\mu\omega^2\hbar^2}{6}\frac{2\mu}{p'+p''}\delta^{(3)}(p'-p'')\,,$$
in which case
$$\psi_{p'}^1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int [E^1_{p'}\frac{2\mu}{p'+p''}\delta'(p'-p'')+\frac{\mu\omega^2\hbar^2}{6}\frac{2\mu}{p'+p''}\delta^{(3)}(p'-p'')]e^{i\frac{p''}{\hbar}x}dp''\,,$$
where
\begin{align}
k&=\frac{p'}{\hbar}\,,
\\
\psi_{p'}^1(x)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}[\frac{\mu E^1_{p'}}{2\hbar^2}\frac{i2kx-1}{k^2}+\frac{\mu^2\omega^2}{24\hbar^2}\frac{i(-4k^3x^3+6kx)+(6k^2x^2-3)}{k^4}]e^{ikx}
\,,
\\
C&=\frac{12\mu E^1_{p'}}{\mu^2\omega^2}\,,
\\
A&=C\frac{2kx}{k^2}+\frac{-4k^3x^3+6kx}{k^4}=-\frac{4}{k}x^3+(C\frac{2}{k}+\frac{6}{k^3})x\,,
\\
B&=C\frac{-1}{k^2}+\frac{6k^2x^2-3}{k^4}=\frac{6}{k^2}x^2-(C\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{3}{k^4})\,,
\\
D&=\frac{\mu^2\omega^2}{24\hbar^2\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\,,
\\
\psi^1_k&=D\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\exp\left[i\left(kx+\arctan\frac{A}{B}\right)\right]\,.
\end{align}

At this point, we can see that
$$\psi^1_k\varpropto z(x)\psi^0_{p'}\,,$$
where
$z=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}e^{i\arctan\frac{A}{B}}$
and as
$x\rightarrow+\infty$, $z(x)\rightarrow-\infty$.

This does not make sense, because the 1D harmonic oscillator or other 1D bound state wave functions should tend to finite values at infinity and in the process of solving also can not let the energy level discrete.

Is there something I'm missing? Or is there no solution to this problem.

Comment: related to [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/756599/36194) and [this article](https://www.nature.com/articles/natrevmats201648) as suggested by @Wolpertinger

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see the connection between this article and the answer I was expecting. I mean, it is well known that the energy levels of 1D harmonic oscillator are discrete, so is it possible to use perturbation theory on free particles to make the originally continuous energy levels discrete?

Comment: @NiveusNix that paper shows that you could have small perturbations that transform unbound states into bound states...

Comment: Can you apply perturbation theory to an unbounded potential?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give a very naive explanation without going into the details of your mathematical demonstration which is very nice.
Starting  by the first-order equation :

$$
\hat{H_0} |\psi^1> + \hat{H'} |\psi^0> = E^0 |\psi^1> + E^0 |\psi^0> \\
E_p (\epsilon)  = E_p^0 + \epsilon <\psi^0|H'|\psi^0> (E_p^0 = <\psi^0|H_0|\psi^0>)
 $$

The unperturbed ground state is purely kinetic $T = E_p^0 = \frac{p'^2}{2\mu} $ and forms an unbound state therefore a continuum in energy. So the discrete energy levels can only arise from the first-order correction with is simply $<\psi^0|H'|\psi^0> = <\psi^0|V|\psi^0>$ the mean value of the perturbed potential $V$ and cannot lead to discrete energy levels.

So basically the perturbation theory applied to a free particle system would hardly lead to bound states if the perturbation is simply **a potential**.

Comment: Use `\rangle` and `\langle` instead of angled brackets on the keyboard, and put the sub- and superscripts outside the \hat, i.e. `\hat{H}_0` instead of `\hat{H_0}`. It looks nicer: $\hat{H}_0$ vs $\hat{H_0}$.