# What is the mathematical definition of bound state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, definition, foundations

While searching why poles of Green’s function corresponds to bound states I came across that I don't know what [bound state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_state) is. Intuitivaly I know that bound
State should be a state that the probability of finding it away from a certain region in space should be almost zero.

But how can we represent it with math?
Is there any references that define it?

Comment: Total energy of the state < potential energy at infinity.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92244/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @john Rennie Can you give me a reference?

Comment: Isn't it kind of obvious? The total energy is a constant so it can never increase. Hence if the energy at infinity is greater than the total energy the particle can never reach infinity i.e. it is bound in some finite region.