# What is the definition of bound state in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, definition, quantum-states, foundations

I asked a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/775744/2451) a while a go what is a bound state and the question was closed because there is a [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92244/2451).

Now since best description we have to describe nature in quantum field theory
How we define bound states in quantum field theory?

Comment: A bound state is basically a stable state of two or more fundamental particles, eg. protons, neutrons, pions are all bound state of quarks and gluons. Glueballs are bound states of gluons, etc.

Comment: One way to identify bound states is via poles in the S-matrix. For example, see https://physicscourses.colorado.edu/phys5250/phys5250_fa19/lecture/lec14-bound-states/

Comment: this may answer https://arnold-neumaier.at/physfaq/topics/bound.html