# Probability flow at any point of a free particle stationary wave in one-dimension!

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, time, schroedinger-equation, scattering

**Update** The plane wave state for a free particle given by $\psi(x,t)=A\exp[i(kx-\omega t)]$ is completely delocalized in space and time. Therefore, the wavefunction is present *everywhere* in space *at all times*. We can, however, 'normalize' this wavefunction, pretending that it is confined in a box of length $L$. In this case, we find, $$\psi(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\exp[i(k_nx-\omega t)]$$ with quantized wavenumber $k\rightarrow k_n$. The position probability density has a spatial profile $$\rho(x)=\psi^*\psi=1/L$$ which is independent of time (like any other stationary state). Moreover, the probability of finding the particle is same everywhere *at all times*. But if we calculate the probability current (flow) it is nonzero: $$j(x)=-\frac{\hbar k}{m}\frac{1}{L}\neq 0.$$ For example, $J_\phi$, the azimuthal component of the current is nonzero in Hydrogen atom for the stationary states.

Therefore, although the *spatial profile* of position probability density does not change with time, there is a propagation!

*How do we interpret this? Should it be interpreted that at any point $x$ the influx of probability is equal to the outflux such that the probability amplitude at any point remains constant in time?*

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12611/2451 and links therein.

Comment: *"Moreover, the probability of finding the particle is same everywhere."* That's inaccurate. The *actual* probability of finding the particle can only be calculated in a *spatial region*, here $P=\int_{\Delta x}\psi^*\psi dx$. In a *point*, $\Delta x=0\implies P=0$.

Comment: *"Therefore, although the spatial profile of position probability density does not change with time, there is a propagation. Aren't these two pictures contradictory?"* Why would they be contradictory? The wave function can evolve in time without the time entering the modulus square (that happens whenever the states are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian).

Comment: The charge density in a wire is constant, yet there is current.

Comment: That the state evolves in time doesn't necessarily mean that the probability must depend on time: the state evolves so that the probability still remains the same in every interval. If you want to perform a measure of the position then the state collapses into an eigenstate of the position operator, which is in general a combination of energy eigenstates with different energies and which evolve differently in time (hence the time dependence does eventually appear in the modulus square).

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to force the modulus square to be time-dependent on an eigenstate of the energy. Localised states are in general not eigenstates of the energy and as such do evolve in time with a factor being present in the modulus square.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for a box is a periodic solution. You can imagine that the particle exits the box, say, through the right wall of the box (I did not check the sign) and immediately enters through the left wall of the box. You may say that this picture is not reasonable, but these solutions are simple and useful. If you want more reasonable solutions for a box, you need to set such boundary conditions at the walls that the current at the walls vanishes. You will then have standing wave solutions, and the probability density will change in time, in accordance with the intuition.

As for the non-vanishing azimuthal component of the current in the hydrogen atom, it corresponds to orbital motion of electrons (along closed trajectories, if we use the correspondence principle).